# regular expression in asp.net

Tags: .net

```
@"^[ 0-9+-\)\(]*$".
```

This is a regular expression on a textbox which i'm using to allow digits,space,+,=,()round brackets. but i'm not getting the desired result.

Comment: How did you put this regex "on the textbox"? Please add some more code.

Comment: internal static string GetRegularExpression(RegexTypes type)
        {
            switch (type)
            {
                case RegexTypes.fax:
                    return @"^[ 0-9+-\)\(]*$";
            }
            return string.Empty;
        }

Comment: How do you expect the textbox to use this method? Please extend your answer with any details and/or repair typos.

Answer (score 0):

Your expression contains +- but your description says you want +=.  It cant be that simple?

Comment: sorry i want +- not = sorry for the mistake

Answer (score 0):

The usual way is to have code like the following in your aspx or ascx file:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="MyTextbox" runat="server"/>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="MyTextboxValidator" runat="server" 
    ControlToValidate="MyTextbox"
    ValidationExpression="[ 0-9+\-\)\(]*]" ErrorMessage="Use digits and some others" />
```

When the user leaves the textbox and/or submits the form, the validator fires and blocks submission on error (displaying the message).

You could change the validation expression server-side:

```
MyTextboxValidator.ValidationExpression = "[ 0-9+\-\)\(]*]";
```

Notes:

- you don't need the ^ and $ to anchor this expression in this validator
- you need to escape the "-" else it will mean a range from "+" to ")"